# Recuperar valor de una variable de hbs en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express, handlebars.js

Estoy estudiando por mi cuenta a base de pegarme cabezazos contra la pared... asi que lo siento se la pregunta es muy obvia.

Estoy trabajando con Nodejs, Express, Handlebars.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente tengo un array de nombres de ficheros, y desde el fichero hbs, selecciono el fichero que quiero utilizar mediante botones.

Render de la pagina que utilizo para mostrar el listado de ficheros(.js):

```
.then((arrlistfiles) => {
    res.render(path.join("selectfile.hbs"),{files:arrlistfiles})
```

Confirmacion del menu modal del fichero que se ha seleccionado(.hbs):

```
{{#each files as |item|}}
<!-- Screen Modal -->
<div id="{{this}}" class="modal">
    <script>

    </script>
    <form class="modal-content" action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="container-modal">
            <h1>Install new version</h1>
            <p>Are you sure install {{this}}</p>

            <p style="color:red;">Only use this option with supervision</p>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <a href="/"><button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button></a>
                <a href="/executeinstallnewversion"><button type="button" onclick='myFunction("{{this}}");' class="deletebtn">Install new version</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto, pero ahora necesito enviar el valor the {{this}} (nombre del fichero) al backend para poder realizar las operativas de descompresión, instalación, etc.

Vengo de trabajar con Xamarin, pero esto no le encuentro ningún parecido y la verdad que me cuesta hacer algo una barbaridad, he estado dos días buscando información (post-get, localstorage, globalvariable,...) pero o no la he entendido o no he sabido implementarla.

Muchas gracias, si se necesita mas información decirme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo tengo "solucionado" realmente no me gusta la forma en la que le he hecho, pero funciona, cualquier otra respuesta mejor, la revisare y la probare.

En el hbs, he añadido ?file={{this}} detrás de la ruta a la nueva pantalla, para que me mande el nombre del fichero como query :

```
{{#each files as |item|}}
<!-- Screen Modal -->
<div id="{{this}}" class="modal">
    <script>

    </script>
    <form class="modal-content" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
        <div class="container-modal">
            <h1>Install new version</h1>
            <p>Are you sure install {{this}}</p>

            <p style="color:red;">Only use this option with supervision</p>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <a href="/"><button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button></a>
                <a href="/executeinstallnewversion?file={{this}}"><button name="select_file" type="button" onclick='myFunction("value");' class="deletebtn">Install new version</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

En el js destino /executeinstallnewversion he añadido dentro de router.get

```
let select_file = req.query.file;
```

Con esto ya tengo el valor de la variable en la nueva pantalla para poder trabajar con ella.

Lo dicho acepto cualquier otra forma de hacerlo dado que esta no me acaba de convencer, aunque funcione.